# Create ProcFS entry in /proc/net

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, procfs

I try to create an entry inside `/proc/net` from a kernel module, like this:

```
struct file *filp = filp_open("/proc/net", O_RDONLY, 0);
struct proc_dir_entry *parent = PDE(filp->f_dentry->d_inode);
filp_close(filp, NULL);

proc_file = create_proc_entry("test", 0644, parent);
```

Crudely taken from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/create_proc_entry-path-help-894814/)

Why does it create my entry like `/proc/test` instead of `/proc/net/test`?

(Note: I'd like too use `create_proc_entry`, not `proc_create`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent kernels you won't find create_proc_entry() anymore, it's been removed completely. Take a look at https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=80e928f7ebb958f4d79d4099d1c5c0a015a23b93. So, you need to use proc_create(). And, pass ->proc_net as parent directory entry. Take a look at this: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/proc.c#n479, this will give you a clear idea.

If you're not using a latest kernel, then you might have create_proc_entry(), therefore might consider using create_proc_entry(), rather proc_create(). But, I think it's best if you cope with current approach. Cause you won't get support for create_proc_entry() with latest kernels.

Comment: Switching to `proc_create` would imply refactoring that is not worth it, that's why I said I need `create_proc_entry`. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to do it is :

proc_file = create_proc_entry("test", 0644, init_net.proc_net);